# Catching the exception tracebacks in a loop and then raising the error(s) at the end of the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, traceback, try-except

I'm trying to catch all exception error(s) and then at the end of the script for it to raise/show all tracebacks...

I have a main script that calls my subscripts for example:

```
    errors = open('MISC/ERROR(S).txt', 'a')

    try:
        execfile("SUBSCRIPTS/Test1.py", {})
    except Exception:
        ## Spread over two calls of errors.write for readability in code...
        errors.write(strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') + "\n")
        errors.write(traceback.format_exc() + '\n\n')

    try:
        execfile("SUBSCRIPTS/Test2.py", {})
    except Exception:
        ## Spread over two calls of errors.write for readability in code...
        errors.write(strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') + "\n")
        errors.write(traceback.format_exc() + '\n\n')

    errors.close()
```

This script uses the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module to retrieve the error from the script...

In the next example this is what my current script sort of looks like:

```
for x in y:
    if "example" in x:
        for tweet in tweetlist:
            # Try
            try:
                twitter.update_status(status=tweet)
                # Do some other stuff here if it suceeeds like...
                print "oo example worked"
            # Damn it failed, grab the whole traceback?
            except Exception as reason:
                FailedTweet = True

# Do some other stuff here like...
print "I did other stuff"

if FailedTweet:
    print reason # Printing the reason because I don't know how to throw the exception error (full error)
```

Basically there is a big loop where it could potentially go wrong around the line: `twitter.update_status(status=tweet)` and if it does I want it to catch the traceback error(s) **could be more than one because it's in a loop** and then when the script finishes I want it to send all the traceback errors back to the main script so it can write them all to the error file.

Example of the error writing to file from the first bit of code:

```
# 17/08/2014 12:30:00
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:\Main.py", line 117, in execute_subscripts
#     execfile("SUBSCRIPTS/Test1.py", {})
#   File "SUBSCRIPTS/Test1.py", line 440, in <module>
#     twitter.update_status(status=string)
#   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\endpoints.py", line 90, in update_status
#     return self.post('statuses/update', params=params)
#   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\api.py", line 234, in post
#     return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
#   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\api.py", line 224, in request
#     content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, api_call=url)
#   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twython\api.py", line 194, in _request
#     retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
# TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), This request looks like it might be automated. To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, we can't complete this action right now. Please try again later.
```

**How would I achieve this, it's kind of hard to explain so if something doesn't make sense please ask.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the traceback data in a list, and then print the contents of the list after the loop is complete.

```
import traceback

reasons = []
for x in y:
    if "example" in x:
        for tweet in tweetlist:
            # Try
            try:
                twitter.update_status(status=tweet)
                # Do some other stuff here if it suceeeds like...
                print "oo example worked"
            # Damn it failed, grab the whole traceback?
            except Exception:
                reasons.append(traceback.format_exc())

# Do some other stuff here like...
print "I did other stuff"

for reason in reasons:
    print reason

# If you want to raise a single exception that shows the traceback for
# each exception, you can do this:
class ChainedException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        msg = "The following exceptions occurred:\n\n{}".format(msg)

if reasons:
    raise ChainedException('\n'.join(reasons))
```

Example usage of `ChainedException`:

```
reasons = []
for i in range(5):
    try:
        raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
    except Exception:
        reasons.append(traceback.format_exc())

if reasons:
    raise ChainedException("\n".join(reasons))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ChainedException("\n".join(reasons))
__main__.ChainedException: The following exceptions occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
Exception: Blah 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
Exception: Blah 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
Exception: Blah 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
Exception: Blah 3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ok.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise Exception("Blah {}".format(i))
Exception: Blah 4
```

**Edit:**

If you really only care about raising a single exception out of the entire list of exceptions, you can do it like this:

```
import traceback

reason = None
for x in y:
    if "example" in x:
        for tweet in tweetlist:
            # Try
            try:
                twitter.update_status(status=tweet)
                # Do some other stuff here if it suceeeds like...
                print "oo example worked"
            # Damn it failed, grab the whole traceback?
            except Exception:
                reason = sys.exc_info() # We're not putting it in a list because you only care about one.

# Do some other stuff here like...
print "I did other stuff"

if reason:
    raise reason[0], reason[1], reason[2]
```

Note that this only works in Python 2.x. If you were using Python 3.x, you would need to use this:

```
if reason:
    raise reason[1].with_traceback(reason[2])
```

Comment: Hmm, good logic. How can I then create an exception so that the main script realises there was/is an error and logs it to file?

Comment: What do you actually want to see logged? Just a notification that one or more exceptions occurred, or all the tracebacks? You can only raise one exception to the parent script, which should that be? One of the actual exceptions that occurred, or a generic exception that indicates one or more status update failed?

Comment: @Ryflex I've updated my answer to show what I *think* you're looking for.

Comment: Uhm, I just had a look through the twitter API again; namely the error codes and it doesn't look like when the code is going through the for loop that I will receive different error codes so it would actually work better in this circumstance to just throw ONE full full traceback `traceback.format_exc()` as shown in my original post; I just don't know how to send the traceback back to the main script... would I do `raise reason` after setting reason as follows: `reason = traceback.format_exc()`)

Comment: I've searched the [sys docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) but I can't find anything about what each part of `exc_info()` does...

Comment: @Ryflex *If no exception is being handled anywhere on the stack, a tuple containing three None values is returned. Otherwise, **the values returned are (type, value, traceback). Their meaning is**: type gets the exception type of the exception being handled (a class object); value gets the exception parameter (its associated value or the second argument to raise, which is always a class instance if the exception type is a class object); traceback gets a traceback object (see the Reference Manual) which encapsulates the call stack at the point where the exception originally occurred.*